# Mostrar solo una vez el texto

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
// Re-usable var's
var cc = []; // Main array
var div = document.getElementById('array');
var t = "";
var w = "";
var c = "";

// End 

// Add element at first w/ push()

for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  cc.push(i);
 w = document.getElementById("array");
 c = document.createElement("p");
 t = document.createTextNode("Push in array: " + i);
 c.appendChild(t);
 w.appendChild(c);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="array"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como puedo mostrar la palabra "*Push in array*" **solo 1 vez**, **pero seguir mostrando los 10 números**, *sin modificar el HTML*

Que quede algo como:

```
Push in array: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder imprimir el texto **una** sola vez, debes usar el bucle, si nos fijamos tienes esta linea:

```
t = document.createTextNode("Push in array: " + i);
```

Lo que quiere decir, que puedes tener acceso al **valor** de la variable `i`, por lo tanto puedes jugar con un operador ternario, dejando tu codigo asi:

```
t = document.createTextNode((i == 0 ? "Push in array: ": "") + i);
```

El operador ternario funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
((condicion) ? SI : NO)
```

Si la condicion se **cumple**, se hara lo que este antes de los dos puntos `:`, en caso **contrario** se hara lo que este despues de ellos.

Asi que lo que hacemos es indicar al codigo, ***cuando el valor de `i` sea 0, imprime "Push in array" al lado del valor de `i`, en caso contrario, solo imprime el valor de i***.

**Nota**

Para poder imprimir todos los elementos en una linea, bastaria cambiar esta linea:

```
c = document.createElement("p");
```

Por esta:

```
c = document.createElement("a");
```

Para que en lugar de crear elementos de tipo `<p>`, cree elementos de tipo `<a>`, que son solo texto, no son parrafos como las etiquetas `<p>`

Voila, el ejemplo:

```js
// Re-usable var's
var cc = []; // Main array
var div = document.getElementById('array');
var t = "";
var w = "";
var c = "";

// End 

// Add element at first w/ push()

for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {

  cc.push(i);

  w = document.getElementById("array");
  c = document.createElement("a");
  t = document.createTextNode((i == 0 ? "Push in array: ": "") + i);

  c.appendChild(t);
  w.appendChild(c);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="array"></div>
</body>
</html>
```